# UNIX: list of files empty, with permissions for the owner, in alphabetical order, adding the result to the file

Tags: unix, find, pipe

I want list the files that are empty, with read permissions for the owner, in alphabetical order, adding the result to the TOP.TXT file.
What is wrong?

```
(find . -type f -empty -perm -u=r ; sort -o ) >> /tmp/top.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` command do not get the output from `find`. You can try something like:

```
find . -type f -empty -perm -u=r | sort -o >> /tmp/top.txt
```